# change foreign key so that it points to another table

Tags: asp.net, sql

I've been going around the net and I just find the solutions or explanations to be convoluted, with dropping and adding constraints and such. First off, I have a foreign key in my Transaction table that points to a Users table which has `UserName` as its primary key, because the Transactions table has to record which user added or modified which record. But now the specs of the program has changed because I ended up utilizing the table provided by ASP.Net, the `aspnet_Users` table. I am now going to point that foreign key to the `UserID` primary key found in `aspnet_Users`. How do I do it properly?

Comment: Please tell me `UserName` is something unique like an email address, and not, say, `"John Smith"`...

Answer (score 1):

JamesP,

It would be much more helpful if you were able to provide some schema information. However I suspect that your Users table Username is a `varchar` datatype and the `UserID` is a `uniqueidentifier` datatype. Because of this you will also need to make sure you have the `UserID` field on the `Transaction` table as a `uniqueidentifier` datatype. If this has been done and all your affected rows have been updated accordingly you can simply modify the foreign key relation property in the management studio using the Relationships function.

If you wanted to do this purely in SQL you will need to dropthe existing relationship such as (psudo code)

```
ALTER TABLE [Transaction] DROP CONSTRAINT [<constraintName>]
```

The recreate the constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE [Transaction] ADD CONSTRAINT [<constraintName>] FOREIGN KEY([UserID]) REFERENCES [aspnet_Users](UserID)
```

Cheers.

Comment: You are correct, my `Username` is `nvarchar` and the `UserId` is a `uniqueidentifier`. But I had a short talk with my supervisor, he insisted on utilizing the `UserName` and not the `UserId`. So what I did is just remove the constraints, and inside my `AddNewRecord` stored proc, I inserted code wherein the procedure would look for a Username in `aspnet_Users` that matches the given Username. But since your answer was the plan that I was aiming for earlier, I'm gonna give you points for that :)